# Removing a widget(floatlayout) in a screen on pressing a button in other screen present in same screen manager inkivy

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

How can I remove a widget present in  screen by pressing a button in a different screen where both screens lie in the same screenManager? for the simplification imagine the case of any mobile app ui where the home page have notification bell with something (a notification pointer with different color) when there is new notification it shows up and when user mark all notification as read the the pointer on the notification bell gets removed. i want to do the same in my app.

I can reproduce code for the same but it would made things more complicated. that's why i have written description of my problem as the problem needs to be understood first. afterwards i can present the code down below. I am able to print the ids present in the home screen by triggering a function (on pressing the read button) in my notification screen

Comment: and code is too long , thats also the reason why i have not attached the code here, will do it when anyone will understand by question

Comment: Add a small example demonstrating what you want, it can almost always be done by writing 100 lines of code

Comment: ok , just going to upload a code snippet riht now